# URI 2399 5% de erro C++

Tags: c++

Galera, meu código está dando 5% de erro e eu não consigo achar um porquê, é a questão do campo minado:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int N, i;
    int qtbombas;
    cin >> N;    

    int tabuleiro[N];

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
    cin>>tabuleiro[i];
    }//inserir bombas no tabuleiro 
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){/*calcular e printar a quantidade de bombas nos arredores*/
        if (i == 0)
            qtbombas = tabuleiro[i]+tabuleiro[i+1]; 

        else if (i == N-1)
            qtbombas = tabuleiro[i]+tabuleiro[i-1];   

        else
            qtbombas = tabuleiro[i]+tabuleiro[i-1]+tabuleiro[i+1];

        cout<<qtbombas<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Link para a questão: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2399

Comment: O que o código deveria fazer? O que ele está fazendo? Quais são as entradas testadas? Quais foram as saídas produzidas? Quais eram as saídas esperadas?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss O enunciado, exemplo de entradas e o resto está no link: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2399

Comment: Seu código me parece correto, embora poderia ter sido melhor. Não consigo ver onde está o erro. O URI te deu alguma mensagem de erro ou razão pela qual algo deu errado?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays com o tamanho definido em tempo de execução, também conhecidos como VLA's (do inglês *variable length array*) não são permitidos pela ISO C++ Standard, então, o problema está nessa linha de código  `int tabuleiro[N];`.

Para você corrigir, você pode usar um `std::vector`, ou alternativamente substituir a linha indicada por `int* tabuleiro = new int[N];` e, no final do programa, antes de `return 0;`, inserir  `delete[] tabuleiro;`.

Por fim, um detalhe: C99 permite esse tipo de array e o compilador GCC, por extensão, aceita eles em C90 e C++, então, é possível que você se depare com programas contendo VLA's em C++, embora isso não seja previsto pela C++ Standard e seja completamente dependente da implementação.
Se tiver interesse em obter mais detalhes sobre VLA's, confira-se: [Arrays of Variable Length](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) e [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)
.